# Looking to get started with SoapUI none pro version for REST Testing?

Tags: rest, testing, soapui

I am looking to get started with SOAPUI none pro version for REST testing, however, all there tutorials are on the Pro version. Do companies use the none pro version and does anyone know a website that has good tutorials to learn SOAPUI without having the pro version? Or is there a better tool for testing REST API's?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 300+ QA engineer and all are using open source SOAPUI [DOWNLOAD](http://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html). We have our in house development team who integrated with Nightly Build and It works fine. Best tutorial is starting Understanding [Groovy Language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/). You don't need to be groovy developer.

Feature understanding is starting from here [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/about-soapui/what-is-soapui.html)

Most of industry using Groovy Programming with SOAP UI and test API. SOAP pro have its own benefits and It is also possible to manage all using SOAP UI open source.